# How to create serial number in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a code:
when I click "delete", it's will remove 1 row of table, now i want, when I delete any row, serial number will start at 1. Ex: I have 1 to 10, now i delete 1, number 2 will change 1, and number 3 will change 2 ... number 10 will change 9, if i delete number 5, so number 6 will change number 5, number 7 will change number 6....and when I add 1 row to table, serial number is last serial number of table added 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var sott = 1;
          var result = $.parseJSON(data);
          //fill data to table

          var stringtogetTr= 'table#bangsp1 tr#tr_' + trGlobal;

          var tr = $(stringtogetTr);
          tr.find('td#stt').html(sott);
          tr.find('td#masp').html(result.masp);
          tr.find('td#donvitinh').html(result.donvitinh);
          tr.find('td#tensp').html(result.tensp);
          tr.find('td#dongia').html(result.dongia);
          tr.find('td#soluongtrongmoithung').html(result.soluongtrongmoithung);
          tr.show();
          tr.addClass('data');

          trGlobal += 1;

          //after fill data, create new tr, has id = tr_*
          createnewTr(trGlobal);

          caltotalvalue();
          } //end if(data)
          }); //end function(data)

          //calculate serial number
          var leng = $("table#bangsp1 tr.data").length;
          if(leng == 0){
             sott = 1;
           }else{ 
             sott += 1;
           }
           if(leng > 0){
             var leng1 = $("table#bangsp1 tr.data").length;
             sott = leng1 + 1;
           }
           });//end $("table#menusp a").click(function()


            }); //end chietkhau
          });//end $(document).ready(function() 



        </script>
```

Now I want when I delete any product in table, serial number will start from 1 on the first row of table.
Please help me.

Comment: provide a sample of html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I sort of understood your question and whipped up an example real quick. This doesn't use your original code but hopefully it helps you conceptually a bit.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  // Grab closest <tr> parent
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  // Grab text inside of .dynamic element nested inside of <tr> parent
  var dynamicValue = $(row).find('.dynamic').text();
  // Change that text into a integer
  dynamicValue = parseInt(dynamicValue);
  // Delete that <tr> row
  row.remove();
  // Finally loop through all the rows and give them a new index number as the order may have changed since deleting a row.
  $('.dynamic').each(function(idx, elem){
    $(elem).text(idx+1);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">1</td>
    <td>Static One Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">2</td>
    <td>Static Two Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">3</td>
    <td>Static Three Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">4</td>
    <td>Static Four Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">5</td>
    <td>Static Five Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">6</td>
    <td>Static Six Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">7</td>
    <td>Static Seven Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">8</td>
    <td>Static Eight Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">9</td>
    <td>Static Nine Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">10</td>
    <td>Static Ten Data</td>
    <td><button>Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this works for me but i didn't understand how idx and elem works, please can you help me to understand this.

Comment: @BikashSaud I added some comments to the JS code. Let me know if there is a specific line or piece of code that doesn't make sense. Worth noting that this code is very old and there is likely a better and more efficient solution for what you need.